# Using XMLHttprequest for android

Tags: android, xml, xmlhttprequest

could anyone clarify if it is a good idea to use the XMLHttprequest object in an Android app?

Comment: The `XMLHttpRequest` object is the browser's implementation of an ajax request. If you're using Java/Swift, that's not gonna be available at all. React Native will be the only framework that allows you to use it. Refer to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html). I believe Android by default uses `HttpUrlConnection`

Comment: @Xenyal is there an alternative whilst still using XML?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` can request whatever data structure you want it to - regardless of whether it's XML, JSON, strings, whatnot.